# Drupal 8.5.1 Upgrade Errors - Where to Look for Troubleshooting?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-8, drush

I am in the process of upgrading a site from 8.3.5 to 8.5.1

I have the codebase updated, I have the modules configured through composer, and upgraded my drush installation with cgr and am running drush 9 within the installation. I have this site running just fine on a dev database in my local environment

I am working on porting in the database from the production server into the dev environment. Using Acquia DevDesktop 2 for the local dev environment.
I can run drush status and everything appears to be fine:

> DB hostname      : 127.0.0.1
>   DB port          : 33067
>   DB username      : drupaluser
>   DB name          : site_migration_851
>   Database         : Connected
>   Drupal bootstrap : Successful
>   Default theme    : site_theme
>   Admin theme      : seven
>   PHP binary       : /Applications/DevDesktop/php5_6/bin/php
>   PHP config       : /Applications/DevDesktop/php5_6/bin/php.ini
>   PHP OS           : Darwin
>   Drush script     : /Volumes/Video_Drive/web/DrupalProjects/site-mig 
>                       ration-851/vendor/drush/drush/drush                     Drush version    : 9.2.3
>   Drush temp       : /tmp
>   Drush configs    : /Volumes/Video_Drive/web/DrupalProjects/site-mig 
>                       ration-851/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml                 Install profile  : standard
>   Drupal root      : /Volumes/Video_Drive/web/DrupalProjects/site-mig 
>                       ration-851                                              Site path        : sites/default
>   Files, Public    : sites/default/files
>   Files, Temp      : /tmp

I cannot load the site in the browser, I get the following error:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again
>   later.Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException:
>   No route found for "GET /" in Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest()
>   (line 144 of vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php).
>
> Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->matchRequest(Object)
>   (Line: 114)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(Object,
>   'kernel.request', Object) call_user_func(Array, Object,
>   'kernel.request', Object) (Line: 111)
>   Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request',
>   Object) (Line: 127)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1)
>   (Line: 68) Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object,
>   1, 1) (Line: 57)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line:
>   47) Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1,
>   1) (Line: 47)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object,
>   1, 1) (Line: 50)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object,
>   1, 1) (Line: 23) Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1)
>   (Line: 664) Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

When I run drush cr, I get the following error:
[error]  Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
Error: Call to undefined function system_rebuild_module_data() in /Volumes/web/DrupalProjects/site-migration-851/core/includes/common.inc, line 1123

I tried running the /core/rebuild.php with the token, which generated fine, but it errored out with the same message as above.

I have manually truncated the "cache_" tables in the database, after reading up on what others have experienced here and on the drupal community site.

I've also checked the configuration manager settings and the uuid is the same as the old dev database. I reset it, tried running the sync changes against the prod db and nothing changed.

Still not able to load the site with the prod DB. The goal is to get the the codebase running with the production database as it has the correct content, etc.

Is there something in the production database that is interfering with the core spinning up the correct routes?

UPDATE:

I re-ran composer update and composer install
Was able to get to the /core/install.php page successfully. 
It tells me that drupal is installed.
the first option of starting over isnt desirable, as I need to keep the content data.

When I go to the /update.php url

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException:
>   You have requested a non-existent service "access_check.db_update". in
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->getDefinition()
>   (line 1024 of
>   vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php).
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->getDefinition('access_check.db_update')
>   (Line: 591)
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->doGet('access_check.db_update',
>   1) (Line: 569)
>   Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get('access_check.db_update')
>   (Line: 182) Drupal\Core\Update\UpdateKernel->handleAccess(Object,
>   Object) (Line: 99) Drupal\Core\Update\UpdateKernel->handleRaw(Object)
>   (Line: 73) Drupal\Core\Update\UpdateKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 28)

When I go to the front page of the site it returns:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again
>   later.Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException:
>   The "node" entity type does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition()
>   (line 133 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php).
>
> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getHandler('node', 'storage') (Line: 169)
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getStorage('node')
>   (Line: 79)
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManager->getStorage('node')
>   (Line: 100)
>   Drupal\Core\ParamConverter\EntityConverter->convert('43',
>   Array, 'node', Array) (Line: 100)
>   Drupal\Core\ParamConverter\ParamConverterManager->convert(Array)
>   (Line: 45)
>   Drupal\Core\Routing\Enhancer\ParamConversionEnhancer->enhance(Array,
>   Object) (Line: 259)
>   Drupal\Core\Routing\Router->applyRouteEnhancers(Array, Object)
>   (Line: 130) Drupal\Core\Routing\Router->matchRequest(Object) (Line:
>   90) Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->matchRequest(Object)
>   (Line: 114)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(Object,
>   'kernel.request', Object) call_user_func(Array, Object,
>   'kernel.request', Object) (Line: 111)
>   Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request',
>   Object) (Line: 127)
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1)
>   (Line: 68) Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object,
>   1, 1) (Line: 57)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line:
>   47) Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1,
>   1) (Line: 47)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object,
>   1, 1) (Line: 50)
>   Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object,
>   1, 1) (Line: 23) Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1)
>   (Line: 664) Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

Running drush dbup & entup return the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function system_rebuild_module_data()
>   in /web/DrupalProjects/site/site/core/includes/update.inc on line 46

additionally drush entup produces the following status, then error

> [success] No entity schema updates required
>   Fatal error: Call to undefined function system_rebuild_module_data()
>   in
>   /web/DrupalProjects/site/site/core/includes/common.inc
>   on line 1123
>   [success] Finished performing updates.

Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands to get a dependency on Upgraded Drupal.

```
composer update
composer install
```

Comment: Hi Samsher, thanks for the response!
I tried your suggestions, but it didn't resolve the issue, see above if you have any more feedback or suggestions.

Comment: Erik, I am sure some dependency is missing that is required in updated Drupal.  Could you please drop the database and install new one or check if it works with the new database or not. If it does not work with even on new database so 100% sure dependency is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

- `composer update`
- `drush updb`
- `drush entup`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for digging up a 5 month old question, I experienced the same errors when I was updating a Drupal 8.5 site to 8.6. I couldn't lose any data within the database so using a new database wasn't going to work for me; I got the above error halfway through running `/update.php`. I ended up getting mine to work by **deleting** the entire `/vendor` directory and re-running:

- `composer install`
- `composer update`
- `drush cr`

Answer (score 0):

After removing the vendor directory from root. Please run composer update command only.
What it will do, it will just install all dependencies based on New Drupal version.

Please let me know if you want entire procedure to upgrade it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please follow processes below. all you need to use this in putty.

1) Install fresh Drupal somewhere out of the main drupal site folder.

```
wget https://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-8.5.1.tar.gz
```

2) untar this file

```
tar -xvf drupal-8.5.1.tar.gz
```

3) go to the new installed drupal root and delete modules, themes, sites folders. for example.

```
rm -rf modules
rm -rf sites
rm -rf themes
```

4) now come back to the root and hit below code.

```
  yes|cp -R drupal-8.5.1/* your_original_drupal_folder_name/
```

5) after that, just go to your drupal root and run `composer update` command.

6) Run `drush updb` at last.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below step to upgrade the Drupal from 8.3.5 to 8.5.1

1. Change the line in composer.json file i.e. "drupal/core": "^8.5.1".
2. Run composer update (It will download all dependencies based on Drupal 8.5.1 with itself)

Then two ways to run Drupal Update
1. Via URL domain/update.php OR
2. drush updatedb

NOTE : Remove the composer.lock if founded at root location.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `CREATE DATABASE` directly unless your defaults are correct.

Try creating it again with `CREATE DATABASE drupal CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci` and then run the import.